# Alternatives to using a CA certificate

Tags: ssl, mitmproxy

Is there an alternative to installing a CA SSL certificate for intercepting traffic for only one site?

I don't like the idea of being able to modify any request, and would like to technically limit it to one domain only, is this possible or if using a MITM do you need to trust the MITM with everything?

Example: You are intercepting all calls to testing site example.com for development reasons, so to dogfood you install a CA certificate onto the devices of the testers. Now you can intercept all domains. The testers dislike this as it invades their privacy.

Is there a way instead to use a certificate installed on devices that will only work for example.com without modifying the certificate given out by the site, or handing over the actual certificate of example.com to mitmproxy?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Could you please explain the issue a bit more? It is unclear why mitm is the tool of choice to solve the issue.

Comment: Edited to provide an example.

Comment: As far as I know, you either route all traffic through the proxy, or you use the network without a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you either route all traffic through the proxy, or you use the network without a proxy. To make the (re)configuration of the network settings easy, a mobile app like proxydroid or a browser extension such as foxyproxy may work for you.